# PostGIS extension on Debian not found: could not open extension control file

Tags: postgis, postgresql, debian

I'm trying to set up the PostGIS extensions on a Postgres 9.1 database on Debian Wheezy, but getting an error:

```
=# create extension postgis;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/postgis.control":
No such file or directory
```

I am not really sure what packages I need to install on Debian to get this working. I've done:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-gdal
$ sudo apt-get install postgis
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis
```

all of which appeared to install fine.

What am I missing?

I've tried to install related packages that I've seen on here, but with no success:

```
$ apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis-scripts
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.1-postgis-scripts
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.1-postgis-scripts'
```

Using autocomplete, apt-get can only see `postgresql-9.1-postgis`. I've even tried `sudo apt-get install postgis*` but it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: This package `postgresql-9.1-postgis` provides Postgis 1.5. Try to install Postgis 2.0.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am facing the same problem